# Integral of a derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable. Analysis provides us with several sufficient conditions for the formula
$$
\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a)
$$
to be true, like continuity (or just Riemann integrability) of $f'$. Can somebody provide me with an example where it is *not* true? Note that the above integral will necessarily have to be a Lebesgue integral. Excuse me if this has already been asked before, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: From baby Rudin, you only need that $f'$ is Riemann integrable

Comment: True, that is one of the conditions. :-)

Comment: I added it to the question, since it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/ x^2)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$. $f'$ exists on $[0,1]$, but is unbounded there (thus, not integrable over $[0,1]$).

Comment: True, it is not Riemann integrable, but could it still satisfy $\int_0^1 f' = f(b) - f(a)$?

Comment: @Gaussler How could it if the LHS does not evaluate?

Comment: "Not integrable" means $\int_0^1 f'$ is not defined.

Comment: @Gaussler: Can you find $f(0)$ above ?

Comment: @DavidMitra, I meant that unboundedness does not prevent if from being Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: It isn't Lebesgue integrable either. See Example 2.2.9, page 97, of [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0CFcQFjAFOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.math.umd.edu%2F~czaja%2Fchap3.pdf&ei=elhmU7CDKuLmyQGa5ICYBg&usg=AFQjCNF2BJ0cOp2yM-6I5p5glnnrESSeBg&cad=rja).

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer, it is a nice example :-) . The only thing I would still like to know is whether there exists a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ with $\int_a^b f' \neq f(b) - f(a)$, even though both sides of the expression are defined.

Comment: This seems relevant to me; one can prove the following: A function $f$ on $[a,b]$ has the form $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x \phi$ for some $\phi\in L_1$ iff $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$. In this case, we have $\phi(x)=f'(x)$ a.e. on $(a,b)$. C.f., Hewitt and Stromberg, *Real and Abstract Analysis*, Theorem 18.17.